# Parse a text file into multiple text file

Tags: java

I want to get multiple file by parsing a input file Through Java.
The Input file contains many fasta format of thousands of protein sequence and I want to generate raw format(i.e., without any comma semicolon and without any extra symbol like ">", "[", "]" etc) of each protein sequence.

A fasta sequence starts form ">" symbol followed by description of protein and then sequence of protein.

For example ►  >lcl|NC_000001.10_cdsid_XP_003403591.1 [gene=LOC100652771] 
[protein=hypothetical protein  LOC100652771] [protein_id=XP_003403591.1] [location=join(12190..12227,12595..12721,13403..13639)]
MSESINFSHNLGQLLSPPRCVVMPGMPFPSIRSPELQKTTADLDHTLVSVPSVAESLHHPEITFLTAFCL
PSFTRSRPLPDRQLHHCLALCPSFALPAGDGVCHGPGLQGSCYKGETQESVESRVLPGPRHRH

Like above formate the input file contains 1000s of protein sequence. I have to generate thousands of raw file containing only individual protein sequence without any special symbol or gaps.

I have developed the code for it in Java but out put is : Cannot open a file followed by cannot find file.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Regards
Vijay Kumar Garg
Varanasi
Bharat (India)

The code is

```
/*Java code to convert FASTA format to a raw format*/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

// java package for using regular expression
public class Arrayren
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  
    {
        String a[]=new String[1000];
        String b[][] =new String[1000][1000];
        /*open the id file*/
        try
        {
            File f = new File ("input.txt"); 
            //opening the text document containing genbank ids
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
            //Reading the file contents through inputstream
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            // Writing the contents to a buffered stream
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            //Method for reading Java Standard data types
            String inputline;
            String line;
            String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            // reads a line till next line operator is found
            int i=0;
            while ((inputline=dis.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                i++;
                a[i]=inputline;
                a[i]=a[i].replaceAll(separator,"");
                //replaces unwanted patterns like /n with space
                a[i]=a[i].trim();
                // trims out if any space is available
                a[i]=a[i]+".txt";
                //takes the file name into an array
                try
                // to handle run time error
                /*take the sequence in to an array*/
                {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(a[i]));
                    String inline = null;
                    int j=0;
                    while((inline=in.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        j++;
                        b[i][j]=inline;
                        Pattern q=Pattern.compile(">");
                        //Compiling the regular expression
                        Matcher n=q.matcher(inline);
                        //creates the matcher for the above pattern
                        if(n.find())
                        {
                            /*appending the comment line*/
                            b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll(">gi","");
                            //identify the pattern and replace it with a space
                            b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","");
                            b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll("|","");
                            b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll("\\d{1,15}","");
                            b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll(".","");
                            b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll("_","");
                            b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll("\\(","");
                            b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll("\\)","");
                        }
                        /*printing the sequence in to a text file*/
                        b[i][j]=b[i][j].replaceAll(separator,"");
                        b[i][j]=b[i][j].trim();
                        // trims out if any space is available
                        File create = new File(inputline+"R.txt");
                        try
                        {
                            if(!create.exists())
                            {
                                create.createNewFile();
                                // creates a new file
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("file already exists");
                            }
                        }
                        catch(IOException e)
                        // to catch the exception and print the error if cannot open a file
                        {
                            System.err.println("cannot create a file");
                        }
                        BufferedWriter outt = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(inputline+"R.txt", true));
                        outt.write(b[i][j]);
                        // printing the contents to a text file
                        outt.close();
                        // closing the text file
                        System.out.println(b[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("cannot open a file");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        // catch the exception and prints the error if cannot find file
        {
            System.out.println("cannot find file ");
        }
    }
}
```

If you provide me correct it will be much easier to understand.

Comment: It will be better if you post the StackTrace that describes the error and a possible cause.

Comment: @Dear Luiggi please copy the code and compile n run you can better understand the problem.

Comment: @Dear Luiggi please copy the code and compile n run you can better understand the problem.
copy the fasta sequence and paste it for three time. The out put should come three new file only with sequence without any special characters. Thanks

Comment: That's not how the site works, remember that some people is pretty busy on job (like me) or doing another stuff, and answers come from expertise, some times from testing the code, and on. P.S.: To add an etiquette you use @VijayKumarSingh (the @ is just behing the name =]).

Answer (score 0):

This code will not win prices, due to missing java expertice. For instance I would expect OutOfMemory even if it is correct.
Best would be a rewrite. *Nevertheless we all began small.*

- Give full path to file. Also on the output the directory is probably missing from the file.
- Better use BufferedReader etc. i.o. DateInputStream.
- Initialize i with -1. Better use `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)`.
- Best compile the Pattern outside the loop. But remove the Matcher. You can do `if (s.contains(">")` as well.
  . One does not need to create a new file.

Code:

```
const String encoding = "Windows-1252"; // Or "UTF-8" or leave away.
File f = new File("C:/input.txt");
BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(f), encoding));
```

...

```
        int i= -1; // So i++ starts with 0.
        while ((inputline=dis.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            i++;
            a[i]=inputline.trim();
            //replaces unwanted patterns like /n with space
            // Not needed a[i]=a[i].replaceAll(separator,"");
```

Comment: JoopEggen sorry your code is not working, output is still cannot open File and cannot find file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains the following two `catch` blocks:

```
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("cannot open a file");
    }
```

```java
    catch(Exception ex)
    // catch the exception and prints the error if cannot find file
    {
        System.out.println("cannot find file ");
    }
```

Both of these swallow the exception and print a generic "it didn't work" message, which tells you that the `catch` block was entered, but nothing more than that.

Exceptions often contain useful information that would help you track down where the real problem is.  By ignoring them, you're making it much harder to diagnose your problem.  Worse still, you're catching `Exception`, which is the superclass of a lot of exceptions, so these `catch` blocks are catching lots of different types of exceptions and ignoring them all.

The simplest way to get information out of an exception is to call its `printStackTrace()` method, which prints the exception type, exception message and stack trace.  Add a call to this within both of these `catch` blocks, and that will help you see more clearly what exception is being thrown and from where.

Comment: Dear Luke might be you are right but I am unable to get it can you run this and provide me the correct code ?

Comment: @VijayKumarSingh: Try putting the line `e.printStackTrace();` in the first of the two `catch` blocks above and `ex.printStackTrace();` in the second.  Is that what you're asking for?